# Simplifying the following expression using Boolean Algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra into sum-of-products (SOP) expressions

. refers to AND 
+ refers to OR

**a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c' + a.b.c'**

This is what I have so far.

**a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c' + a.b.c'**

= (b'.c').(a'+a) + a.b.c'

= b'.c' + a.b.c'

Anyway to simplify it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use associativity when operators are mixed:

$$a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c' + a.b.c' \neq (b'.c').(a'+ a) + a.b.c'\tag{1}$$

It is true that $a'.b'.c' = b'.c'.a'$, by commutativity of ".", but it is not legitimate/not valid to impose parentheses to group $(a' + a)$ as you did.

You can use the ***distributive laws***, and you might want to use ***Demorgan's Laws***, as well.

Example: for using the distributive law, and the fact that $b' + b = 1$ 
$$a.b'.c' + a.b.c' = a.c'.b' + a.c'.b = a.c'(b'+b) =  a.c'$$

Now we've simplified our expression to

$$a'.b'.c' + a.c'\tag{2}$$

There's a common term of $c'$ in each of these products, so we can simplify further. See what you come up with, and I'll work with you to clarify/confirm, etc. if you have any more questions.

$$a'.b'.c' + a.c'=(a'.b' + a).c' $$ $$= [(a'+a).(b'+a)].c' $$ $$= (b'+a).c' = b'.c' + a.c' $$ $$= a.c' + b'.c'$$

Comment: I see. Then how do I approach the question above?

Comment: Do you know how the distributive laws work? Do you know DeMorgan's?

Comment: distributive rule
x.(y+z) = (x.y) + (x.z)

I know DeMorgan rule.

Comment: a.b′.c′+a.b.c′=a.(b′.c′+b.c′)
is not equal to  a.b′.c′+a.b.c′=a.c'(b′+b) ?

Comment: I am really lost. Do you mind guiding me through this question?

Comment: Ok. I get it now! :)
Thanks! :)

Comment: So I have a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c' + a.b.c'
By doing a.b′.c′+a.b.c′=a.c′.b′+a.c′.b=a.c′(b′+b)=a.c′
I will have a'.b'.c' + a.c′ right?
Can this be simplify further?

Comment: c' . (a'.b' + a) 
Is this correct?
From here, are there anymore ways to simplify this?

Comment: so I will have c'.(a'.a + b'.a)?

Comment: I meant to write the distributive rule: (x.y + z) = (x + z).(y+z)$

Comment: You're welcome! Turns out, this problem was pretty much all about the distributive laws!

Comment: +1 for the time you type this difficult answer. Full of '

Answer (score 1):

Please follow @amWhy's approach. Once you get it, you may try to understand this:

$$a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c' + a.b.c'$$ $$=a'.b'.c' + a.b'.c'\mathbf{+ a.b'.c'}+ a.b.c'$$ $$=b'.c'(a'+a)+a.c'(b+b')$$ $$=b'c'+a.c'$$